Gradle Task 'assembleDebug' Failed After Flutter Upgrade: Execution Failed for Task ':app '
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH2015 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> A build operation failed.
      Cannot parse result path string:                                           
   > Cannot parse result path string:                                           

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i only upgrade my flutter because i have to do it for the mobile_scanner package

I hope you've set minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in your android/app/build.gradle.
